# ansi-term hangs on C-s

Tags: emacs

When I type C-s using `ansi-term` in emacs, the shell becomes unresponsive. I can move the cursor around in the shell but I can't type anything. Is this some sort of obscure "feature", or is it a bug? How can I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an obscure feature: [XON/XOFF flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control). `C-s` tells the computer to stop sending data to the terminal, because the terminal can't print or display the data as fast as the serial line is sending it. It made a lot of sense in the 1970s, but now it's pretty useless.

Press `C-q` to tell the computer to send data again. Press `C-v C-s` to send a `C-s` character to the application, and likewise for `C-q`.

If you want to turn off this feature, put `stty -ixon` in your shell startup file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`). I don't know of a way to turn it off automatically by configuring `ansi-term` itself.

Comment: Actually, XON/XOFF has it uses to this day. When a lot of output is being dumped to the terminal, it can be difficult to read even a single line of text (because everything scrolls too fast). And sometimes it's just what you want to: read output sporadically. In that case - `C-s`, read, `C-q`. Not sure it's useful in `ansi-term`, or, for that matter, in any other Emacs's terminal, but for other common emulators, it's a thing.